# GestureImageView goes blank when trying to set bitmap from camera programatically

Tags: android, imageview, gestures

I am using:
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

- on load of the app, it has a placeholder image in a GestureImageView that pinch/zooms appropriately. I have a button that when clicks fires a camera intent, saves the file, and then I wish to set that image to be the source bitmap used in the gestureimageview.

  GestureImageView imageView = (GestureImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewOne);

  ```
  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

  getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUriOne, null);


                  try {
  Bitmap mybitmap =  android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUriOne);

   imageView.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);
  ```

  }

For a normal imageview, that works. But for the GestureImageView, the image stays as the original once returned from the camera intent, and if touched disappears.

To check it's not the bitmap that's the problem, I tried

```
int idTwo=getResources().getIdentifier("com.jazz.test1:drawable/second_photo", null, null);

imageView.setImageResource(idTwo);
```

I.e. set the imageview to an existing resource, but this has the same problem.

If I call that setImageResource code *before* the intent, it does work.

Any ideas how to debug? There are no errors in the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolution is here:

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/issues/21

- hadn't noticed it when I initially looked at the github issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your **initMethod** function. With this code it will work properly  (**GestureImageView.java** file in com.polites.android package).

```
protected void initImage() {
        if (this.drawable != null) {
            this.drawable.setAlpha(alpha);
            this.drawable.setFilterBitmap(true);
            if (colorFilter != null) {
                this.drawable.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
            }
            // Keppel.Cao
            layout = false;
            startingScale = -1.0f;
        }

        if (!layout) {
            requestLayout();
            // Keppel.Cao
            // redraw();
            reset();
        }
}
```

Like Dave said. More you can find here [Issue 21](https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/issues/21)